# How to add dependencies to Grails 3

Tags: dependencies, grails-3.0

Good day. I need to add runtime "com.google.guava:guava:18.0" dependency to grails 3 application to build.gradle file. I add it in dependencies {} block, but nothing happens, I don't get dependency, my classes can't resolve imports which is needed.

Comment: Show us the code where you add the dependency. Also, what is the exact error or problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this [page](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.guava%7Cguava%7C18.0%7Cbundle)

```
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
```

hopes it will help you.